# How do you change the default light color taskbar on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

All new windows 10 laptop comes with a light color taskbar which I don't like. I want to change it to some other color, something darker.

How do I change this? I tried doing this from settings but couldn't.

Comment: You can make the Taskbar a darker color of the main desktop color in settings. Start, Settings, Personalization, Colors, and enable Taskbar and Titles both. The accents work fine here.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the taskbar color you want to change, and not the entire
Windows theme, you may need a third-party product.

The free Windows Store application
[TranslucentTB](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/translucenttb/9pf4kz2vn4w9?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
may help here:

> TranslucentTB offers you control over the appearance of your taskbar. You can customize the effect and color of it, and combine states (maximised window, Start Menu open, Cortana open and Timeline open), each one with a customizable taskbar appearance to reach a dynamically changing and visually pleasing taskbar.